# Quantity figure entered is being multiplied by itself at checkout

Tags: checkout, cart, quantity

(Further investigation showed that this bug was causing the quantity figure to be multiplied by itself which this question is updated with at the bottom as opposed to multipled by 10 as we initially thought when we raised this question).

Absolutely stumped on this one. Posting the quantity is multiplying the figure entered by 10 yet doesn't update the actual visible figure displayed in the field.

So if I updated the quantity on the checkout page from 10 to 50, Magento thinks that the quantity is 500 but still only shows 50. So this is resulting in lots of errors saying the product isn't available in the requested quantity... Therefore most customers cannot checkout.

Have spent an entire day testing this and trying to debug before I found this to be the problem.

I can't see any extensions overriding related functions or controllers. And the code for the qty input field and add to cart button appears to be the same as Magento's core. I've really got no idea where this is happening. It is multiplying by 10 every time, that figure doesn't vary.

We've also reverted to default theme and the same thing happens.

This is affecting both stores - I previously made a mistake in saying only store 2 was affected.

Please let me know any code you'd like to see or if you have any ideas to what might be causing this. Thanks in advance.

## Edit 1: Adding sample / related code in use...

There is no `checkout/cart` overrides for the wholesale store so it falls back to what is in use for the retail (default) store.

```
/app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/checkout/cart.phtml
```

Quantity column:-

```
<th rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>" class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?></th>
```

Is inside the form:-

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>" method="post">
```

In...

```
/app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml
```

The quantity field:-

```
<td class="a-center">
    <input name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" value="<?php echo $this->getQty() ?>" size="4" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="span1" maxlength="12" />
</td>
```

I don't see anything unusual with the above, further on from this, I think it will only use Magento core functions to update the quantity field? And we've just replaced the entire `/app/code/core/Mage` from a fresh download of Magento 1.7.

From a product view page, you can update the quantity and it successfully adds to cart, it is only once you view cart at `/checkout/cart` that Magento then decides to multiply the quantity field by 10.

What is affected:-

- Both stores are affected.
- Configurable products only (where associated products are added to cart).

Image of problem below...

[image: cart qty error]

## Edit 2: Don't know if the stack trace gives anything of use?

```
2013-08-01T11:08:06+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Not all products are available in the requested quantity' in /var/www/vhosts/[domain]/httpdocs/app/Mage.php:594
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/[domain]/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock.php(144): Mage::throwException('Not all product...')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/[domain]/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Observer.php(602): Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock->registerProductsSale(Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/[domain]/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer->subtractQuoteInventory(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#3 /var/www/vhosts/[domain]/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Fooman_AdvancedPromotions_Model_CatalogInventory_Observer), 'subtractQuoteIn...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#4 /var/www/vhosts/[domain]/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('sales_model_ser...', Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/[domain]/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(187): Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_model_ser...', Array)
#6 /var/www/vhosts/[domain]/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(249): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitOrder()
#7 /var/www/vhosts/[domain]/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(774): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
#8 /var/www/vhosts/[domain]/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(511): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveOrder()
#9 /var/www/vhosts/[domain]/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveOrderAction()
#10 /var/www/vhosts/[domain]/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
#11 /var/www/vhosts/[domain]/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#12 /var/www/vhosts/[domain]/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/[domain]/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#14 /var/www/vhosts/[domain]/httpdocs/wholesale/index.php(89): Mage::run('wholesale', 'store')
#15 {main}
```

## Edit 3: Extending `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item`

Please see [this issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6281/update-quantity-of-products-in-cart-to-the-max-available-if-quantity-entered-is) which could be related to the cause of this one. Reverting this change though does not make the problem go away. All sessions, cache etc cleared. This is driving us nuts.

## Edit 4: Multiplied by itself not by 10...

Further investigation uncovers that the quantity figure is actually getting multipled by itself (as opposed to by 10 as originally claimed).

For example:-

- entering 6 takes 36 off stock (6x6)
- entering 10 takes 100 off stock as (10x10)
- entering 3 takes 9 off stock as (3x3)

Illustrated below:-

[image: Magento quantity field working]

[image: Magento quantity field not working]

[image: Magento stock levels that show that the above quantity orders should work]

Quantity of 6 works, quantity of 7 doesn’t. 38 in stock. (6x6=36 below 38) works / (7x7=49 above 38) fails.

(Updated title of question to reflect new findings)...

## Edit 5: We've also raised this as an issue at Magento's bug tracker

It definitely seems like a core Magento bug, we've exhausted every possible option and scenario having ripped the website to pieces and re-pieced it bit by bit, testing throughout the process. Issue just appears out of nowhere once the site is put together but remains if you revert back to default Magento core everything! (not got much hair left at the moment)... [Link to issue in Magento Bug Tracker](http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue?issue=15213).

## Edit 6: Customer Accounts / Shipping Methods

Issue seems very closely related to customer accounts and shipping methods. Will provide more issue when I have it...

## Edit 7: This is now fixed, we've identified the bug - answer to follow shortly.

Comment: Just shooting in the dark here, but maybe it has something to do with the locale of your store. Try changing it to `en_US` (if it's not that already) and see what happens. If the locale is already `en_US` then consider this just an other stupid comment passing through.

Comment: The locale default config is set to English (United Kingdom) and both stores are using this default config. Is this what you were referring to? Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I had a similar problem with a dropdown quantity multiplying by two. Can you post some code as I might be able to help...

Comment: Sure thing, that would be greatly appreciated. I'll extend my question with code in use shortly. Thanks.

Comment: Try `quote_item_set_qty` event debugging. Also can you reproduce the same issue on your development environment?

Comment: Thanks for checking this out Ivan - I've updated question with more information if of use. Will look into event debugging now. Thanks

Comment: Hi Geoff, I see our extension mentioned in there. Could you please email me support@fooman.co.nz so that we can check if there is anything funky going on with one of your promotions.

Comment: I've emailed you Fooman, great spot on noticing that, thanks.

Comment: Ivan, please could you explain how I could debug the event `quote_item_set_qty` ? Your help would be greatly appreciated as I'm getting nowhere after spending two days on this now. Thanks.

Comment: My money is on the `Fooman_AdvancedPromotions_Model_CatalogInventory_Observer` observer. It looks like the only thing that's not in the core. Try disabling the extension and see what happens.

Comment: We've replicated the entire site at a new dev locations and re-pieced together bit by bit. Currently the Fooman extension is not installed and we're experiencing the issue again. We then added the extensions one by one until we encountered the issue. It seemed to happen around the same time as we extended `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item` (but this was shorlty after enabling the extensions). We've reverted all changes and still got same issue. Updated question with what we extended if of relevance - although could be coincidence.

Comment: Hi. Is this with logged in customers? Have you tried with a fresh database (clean database?), or with no customer records? I have had a similar issue where totals got doubled in cart/checkout due to a bug in customer address entry. Each customer got two address   entry lines in the address table, and that caused an issue with cart totals calculations, causing all totals to double in qty (thus qty * qty), as soon as customer logged in. possible your issue is due to data in db, rather in code?

Comment: Hi, I expanded my comment above to an answer, to allow some more details.

Comment: Thanks for your responses @ProxiBlue. Issue isn't always apparent, but when it is, the error is only triggered after customer details is entered at checkout steps or they are logged in or have an active session. Sometimes, I don't get the issue at all and can checkout fine. We've rebuilt the site multiple times, seems okay with clean database/no customer records but then, it is sometimes okay with the current database too - will explain further in reply to your answer, thanks.

Comment: So, been waiting in anticipation for the why.....

Comment: I've not forgotten, just been really busy - will try and update this one with answer this week though. Thanks for following it up.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a similar issue I had about a year ago.

The end result was the same as what you have: totals got doubled by qty (qty * qty)

The problem was tracked down to when customer address got added to the order object, it got added twice as delivery address. Thus the order object had 3 addresses:

- 1 - Billing
- 2 - Shipping
- 3 - shipping (duplicate of #2)

I forget why this happened :( (I seem to recall an observer event doing something funky)

The same happened to the quote object (thus cart)

Since totals calculation hang directly off address objects, totals got doubled by qty.

An easy why to test if you are having the same issue, wipe out the sales_flat_order_address table, and enter checkout. Then check the table for address entries for your order. you should have 2 entries in there.

Additionally, since the issue is related to database entries, once the bug was fixed, it looked like the problem remained/was not fixed. It required removing the duplicates from the database for the problem to resolve for existing quote/order objects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Proxiblue. Seems like we've encountered the same bug as you did. Exactly the same frontend outcome with qty*qty yet we only appear to be getting two entries (x1 billing, x1 shipping) in the `sales_flat_order_address` table. Definitely seems related to customers, cookies / sessions or accounts / address records though. We've confirmed there is no issues with the code, theme, extensions as was able to replicate in Magento's base. I think you're very close to what is causing the issue with your answer - we'll continue to investigate. Thanks.

Comment: @GeoffJackson Have you tried putting a debugger breakpoint in the totals calculation part, especially where it iterates the addresses to build the totals? You should then at least see if the object internals are correctly populated on address data, and also if it gets called again, and trace back to where....thsi is how I tracked down my issue.
Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::collectTotals()

I do recall my issue ended up being a custom module, so my own fault :), it was not related to core functionality.

Comment: Currently installing Xdebug on the server where this live website is to debug. Will try your suggestion and hopefully will shed some light onto the issue. Will feedback with more info when I have it - thanks for your suggestions and help.

Comment: We have seen this issue on our checkout, we saw the multiplication of the cart total by 4 before shipping. Following reading this thread I reverted the test site to default theme and then selected "Checkout with Multiple Addresses" (hidden in our store theme). Selecting this option cleared the issue for this user / store.